# Why += is considered as an assignment operator while >= is not?

Tags: python-3.x, assignment-operator, boolean-expression

I was thinking why the '=' in '+=' is considered as assignment while '=' in '>=' is not considered as such. There is no importance behind this question but some random thought of a beginner. For example purpose, you can consider that

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a += 2 # array updated and assigned to a

a>=2 # becomes a boolean indexing filter
```

Comment: `a += 2` is a shorthand for `a = a + 2`, while `a >= 2` is just a relational operator of the same type as `a > 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a += 2` changes the value of `a`.  It *reassigns* it's value to be two more than it was before.  By the way, `+=` as a whole is the assignment operator, not just the `=`.

`a>=2` does not change the value of `a`.  Yes, it becomes true or false.  But 'true' or 'false' is all it is.  It does not get *assigned* to anything.  The value of `a` is as it was before.

You can do `b = a>=2`.  But in that case, `=` is the assignment operator because it is what assigns the value to b.